weird render with react-native 0.76 i didn't have in 0.74
i have this simple component who render separator as orange dot. i use it since 2 years. now with react native 0.76 update it begin acting strange
import React, {memo} from 'react';
import {theme} from 'styles/theme';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const _WIDTH = 3;
const _MARGINRIGHT = 10 + _WIDTH;

const renderDots = () => {
  let dots = [];
  const elementSize = _MARGINRIGHT + _WIDTH;

  for (let index = 0; index < windowWidth / elementSize; index++) {
    dots.push(<SeparatorDot key={index} />);
  }

  return dots;
};

const Separator = () => {
  return <SeparatorView>{renderDots()}</SeparatorView>;
};

export default memo(Separator);

const SeparatorView = styled.View`
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
`;

const SeparatorDot = styled.View`
  margin-right: ${_MARGINRIGHT}px;
  height: ${_WIDTH}px;
  width: ${_WIDTH}px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: '#f6a200';
`;

do you have an idea why ? thanks
each time i open the same it render differently



i could maybe use alternate orange and white dot like this but i have many different color in background so i need to configure them all
  for (let index = 0; index < windowWidth / elementSize; index++) {
    dots.push(<SeparatorDot key={index} />);
    dots.push(<SeparatorDotWhite key={index} />);
  }

 
 

const SeparatorDot = styled.View`
  height: ${_WIDTH}px;
  width: ${_WIDTH}px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: ${theme.orangeDark};
`;
const SeparatorDotWhite = styled.View`
  margin-right: ${_MARGINRIGHT}px;
  height: ${_WIDTH}px;
  width: ${_MARGINRIGHT}px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: ${theme.white};
`;

